# how to get multiple values from text-box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have text-box that contain multiple names that are separated by comma.  I want to get each name from the text-box and insert into database.  How can i do this?
Names in the text-box are like this:

```
Mike Drew, Andy Moore, John Edward and so on...
```

asp textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfUID" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />
```

code behind

```
 protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string customerName = Request.Form[txtSearch.UniqueID];
            string UID = Request.Form[hfUID.UniqueID];
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Name: " + customerName + "\\nID: " + UID + "');", true);
        }
```

Comment: Use String.Split(',') to get an array of all your names from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to seperate the comma seperated values in the textbox like this:

```
string[] str = customerName.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
```

and then you can add the values from the string array to the database.

Comment: i am not able to get it can you please show me little bit more example of how i can do this?  thanks